# Why won't ls command show users in home directory?

Tags: unix, ls

In unix, when I create a user with useradd it creates their home directory in /home by default. But I specified another user to have its home directory in /home/summer. When I use the ls command inside my directory it doesn't list my new user as /home would. What am I doing wrong? The new user exists in the etc/passwd file.

Comment: What's the exact command you have run to do so?

Comment: Are you saying you added newuser as /home/summer/newuser and they aren't showing up as /home/newuser?  If so, isn't that intended behavior?

Comment: nkn: i just run "ls" inside the home/summer folder
fixer1234: no I added newuser as home/summer

Comment: If the answer is the solution, accept it, or submit your own answer to the question

Comment: If summer is the new user and you created /home/summer, you will see summer when you look in /home.  You won't see summer inside /home/summer.

Answer (score 1):

`grep` for the user in /etc/passwd.  Their fully qualified directory path will be defined in there if the user was set up correctly.  Also make sure you use `sudo` to look at another users home directory in case the permissions are disabling your view.

```
sudo ls -la /home/summer
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to be either root or run the last command with `sudo` (elevated permissions) to view all the  contents of `/home` directory.

Use `sudo ls /home/*user*` to view all files and folders in the home directory of that user

Answer (score 0):

I realized that I thought writing the home directory as home/summer would automatically create their home directory with the user's username. The proper way to create the home directory is home/summer/username,  while I was only writing home/summer.